# Why am I not able to execute minikube like other executables, even when it is installed and ready?

Tags: docker, containers, minikube, alpine-linux

Learning kubernetes, I am trying to spin a minikube cluster in an alpine container running on docker. Regardless of whether this is possible or not, I don't understand why kernel is unable to see that "minikube" exists as an executable file, in /usr/local/bin. I am able to execute "kubectl" though which exists at the same path.

I have already tried to execute "minikube", "./minikube" from root and /usr/local/bin paths. I've also looked up a [similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1321746/sudo-minikube-returns-command-not-found), but the solution didn't help.

Below is what I see on my screen. Both "kubectl" and "minikube" appear green in color.

```
/usr/local/bin # ls -l
total 96540
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      42985504 Aug 18 11:31 kubectl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      55869264 Aug 18 11:36 minikube
/usr/local/bin # minikube
/bin/sh: minikube: not found
/usr/local/bin # ./minikube
/bin/sh: ./minikube: not found
/usr/local/bin # minikube --help
/bin/sh: minikube: not found
/usr/local/bin #
```

I expect "minikube" to execute and throw a help or error message. However, what I am seeing is an error from Kernel unable to find any executable with that name.

Comment: the error is probably referring to a missing dependency. I agree, it is misleading.

Comment: What might the dependency be? Can you point me in a direction where I can look further?

Answer (score 8):

One of the things that makes the Alpine base image small is that it uses a reduced version of core system libraries that can be incompatible with some binaries, apparently including the `minikube` binary.  Either of these works for me:

```sh
# The hard way
/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 ./minikube-linux-amd64
```

```sh
# The slightly easier way
apk add libc6-compat
./minikube-linux-amd64
```

This having been said, it still won't work, because Minikube launches a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a virtual machine, and you can't launch a VM from inside a Docker container.  You need to run this command directly on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about incompatibility. I am still unable to execute "./minikube-linux-amd64" by either of the ways mentioned above, but I just won't pursue it anymore; it ain't worth the effort.

Comment: Today, I killed all containers and restarted them, this somehow motivated my docker engine to start recognizing minikube and now that command is running. Damn. Now I'll have to try to complete what I was trying earlier. Read somewhere that I will need dind (docker in docker) to make it happen.

Comment: Docker releases an official dind image, and an official compose image https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/ and https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose

You need to understand the first image before moving on, imo.